# I have a transfer function in s domain convert to time domain

Tags: laplace-transform

I have a transfer function of $\frac{1}{s^2}$ in $s$ domain that represents a $\frac{\text{output}(s)}{\text{input}(s)}$.

Say I put a constant DC input as input (s) or just input in time domain that is constant over time.

What does this look like as $\frac{\text{output}(t)}{\text{input}}$ in time domain or what is its transfer function in time domain?

Comment: Hi, welcome to DSP.SE! Are you familiar with the Laplace Transform of the Unit Step function?

Comment: I am not putting in a step.  It's just a constant input.

Comment: That is exactly what a step function is.

Comment: If you mean constant for all time then you need to look into the Bilateral Laplace Transform and the Dirac Delta function.